# Magento 1.6 attributes in admin

Tags: php, attributes, magento

Magento is acting a bit weird and not quite sure why.

It was working before but now when I add an attribute to an attribute set and then create a configuration product when I get to the "select configurable products" stage the attributes I check dont show up on the actual product creation page.

But here's the strange thing. It's as if the system inverts the options. E.g if I have 3 attributes on there and I select all three, on the product creation I cannot see any of my chosen attributes.

If I select the first and third attributes when I click continue the second attribute shows up etcbut not the actual ones I selected.

So in essence it seems to show the attributes I don't actually select. The opposite of what it should do.

Hope someone can shed some light and help fix. No idea what's going on.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes must be set on the *simple products* that you attach to your *configurable product*.

For my configurable product **Foo Cleaning Supplies** I selected *Product Type* as my configurable attribute. When I view the *Associated Products* tab to select the *simple products* that are associated with my configurable product I am only shown the products with the *Product Type* attribute set, since those are the only ones that can be part of my configurable product.

[image: Screenshot of a configurable Magento product]